# Add className in a row with DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this for create the table:

```
head.push({
  'data': 'Row',
  'title': 'Entity',
  'className': 'description',
  'render': function(data, type) {
    if (type == 'display') {
      return data.Entity;
    }
    return data.Entity;
  }
});
```

And then I insert the rows so:

```
var rows = function(){
    var datos = [];
      for (var i in obj.data){
        datos.push({Row: obj.data[i]})
      }
    return datos;
}();

var options = {
  "paging": false,
  "info": false,
  "searching": false,
  'columns': head,
  'data': rows,
  "initComplete": function() {
    this.fnAdjustColumnSizing(true);
  },

};
```

Well, the table works but one of the rows has to have other class, but I don't know how or where do it. Can I add in "datos.push"?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I would try inserting the class before you do datos.push()

```
var rows = function(){
    var datos = [];
    for (var i in obj.data){
        obj.data[i].push({'className': 'theClass'})
        datos.push({Row: obj.data[i]})
    }
    return datos;
}();
```